# Using a variables from another method in the same class -c#

Tags: c#, variables, methods, global-variables

```
public class APICreateTriageContactSteps

    public void ThenICreateTheContact()
    {
        Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity contact = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity("contact");
        Guid contactId = m_OrgServ.Create(contact);
    }

    public void ThenIRetrieveTheEntity(String entity)
    {

    Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity retcontact = m_OrgServ.Retrieve(entity, contactId, new ColumnSet(true));
      }

    public void ThenVerifyThatHhDevenv_LocalIsTheNameOfTheContact(String attributevalue)
    {
    String contactname = retcontact.GetAttributeValue("fullname").ToString();
    Assert.AreEqual(attributevalue, contactname);

    }

    public void ThenIDeleteTheEntity(String entity)
    {
    m_OrgServ.Delete(entity, contactId);
     }
```

I want to use variables that I have defined in a method. Now I want to use the value of that variable another method. So how will I call this, do I need to set it as a global variable at the start ?

The variables I want to use are contactId and retcontact in 2 methods.
Currently I am getting the error - "The name does not exist in the current context"

Comment: You need to look into static vs non static classes and variables

Answer (score 1):

you need to use fields/properties if you want to work on the same data with different methods in the same class.

```
class xyz{

string a;

MethodA()
{
 a = "a";
}
MethodB()
{
 a = "b";
}

}
```

alternatetivly you can use a "MainMethod" which calls every single method and give the variable you want to share as parameter

```
   class xyz{

    void MainMethod()
{
 string a = "main";
a = MethodA(a);
a = MethodB(a);
}   
    string  MethodA(string a)
    {
     a = "a";
    return a;
    }
    string MethodB(string a)
    {
     a = "b";
    return a;
    }

    }
```